# Wamp is not using latest version of php

Tags: php, cmd, wamp

In `CMD` I want to create a new laravel project, but then I get the following error:

`This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.`

In wamp I selected: PHP > VERSION > 7.0.10, but its still using the wrong php version.

```
C:\wamp\www>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Hopefully someone can help me out;)

Comment: If you run the cmd php -v what is the output?

Comment: 'PHP 5.6.25 (cli)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installation of `laravel` depends on the `composer`, when you install your `composer` it asks for `php version` location, You need to **re-install** the `composer` and point the `php` to the required version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks;)

Comment: Glad it worked. But make sure while browsing the application through wamp the required version is selected.

Comment: Did the trick for me as well, thanks @NitishKumar

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Wamp server are you running?

from what I remember it installs both 5.6 and 7 then uses a batch file in the /bin/ directory to determine which version to use in the terminal.

Look in C:\wamp\bin for php.bat then edit it to point from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25 to C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.*.*

This should give you the cli php version you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

"CMD" PHP version is not defined in WAMP's configuration.

- If you are using PHP through Windows Environment variable "Path", check there, you probably have a previous version configured.
- If you are using a batch file, check the version you call in your *.bat file which version you are calling.

Comment: You also need to restart your "cmd" window after changing "path" environment variable.